# Benefits of having both non-clustered and clustered indexes

Tags: t-sql, indexing

Let's assume we have table A with columns col1, col2 and col3. And we have non-clustered index on the col2 (3 levels).
When you use non-clustered index for searching and want to return the values of col3 it reads 3 pages from the index and then by the reference moves to the database and reads additional one page.

Now let's suppose that we have also clustered index on col1. Then for the same searching it will read 3 pages from non-clustered index, then do key look-up in clustered index (another 3 pages at least).

So having clustered index increases costs. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I'm referring to this (often ignored) phenomenon as "clustered index penalty".

Here is an article I wrote about that, also featuring some benchmarks: http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2014-01/unreasonable-defaults-primary-key-clustering-key

Comment: thanks a lot. I had doubts about my position.
I liked your article.))))